# IIS Reverse Proxy Rule From Different Ports

Tags: iis, proxy, server, port, reverse

I've been trying to make a Reverse Proxy rule in IIS for when a specific port is used to access the site. For example:

I want to be able to set up multiple rules, one for port 80 and one for port 8080 so that if port 80 is accessed through http://example.com one rule is triggered and if it is accessed through port 8080 as in http://example.com:8080 then a different rule is triggered. The Input conditions for the rules don't seem to allow for this as it says the Input is "URL path after '/'".

Is there a way to do this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just realised that you can specify additional conditions for the Inbound rules.

So you can use one of them and check if {SERVER_PORT} matches against the port number you care about. This appears to work for me.